# How to create 2d heatmap from 1d array in python?

Tags: python, heatmap, correlation

As a result of my own function, I get 1d array something like `[0.4, 0.6, 0.2, 0.3, 0.9, 0.7]`

Now I want to make a heatmap with it, for example,
0.7 
0.3 0.9 
0.4 0.6 0.2

or

1 0.7 0.3 0.4 
0.7 1 0.9 0.6 
0.3 0.9 1 0.2 
0.4 0.6 0.2 1 
with some proper labels.

How do I do this? Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you got the right answer then mark the right answer for others. Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by matplotlib library inside python.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [0.4, 0.6, 0.2, 0.3, 0.9, 0.7]

// reshape your data into 2D array
data = np.array(data).reshape(2, 3)

//  Now plot heatmap for your data show in graph
plt.imshow(data, cmap='hot')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry I saw your response too late. Thanks for it, but actually I want to make it lower triangle like I exemplified in my question, not 2x3.